# Difference of outputs between geom bar and ggbarplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

Ok so basically, I don't understand why when I do `ggplot + geom_bar` and `ggbarplot` from `ggpubr`, I've two different outputs (like really different one goes to 60 max and the other one to almost 85) on the same condition.

```
ggbarplot(data.long4, 
          x = "Dir_NF", 
          y = "Beta", 
          add ="mean_se",
          palette = "Set1", 
          fill = "Crit_Type", 
          position = position_dodge(width = 0.9),  
          ylab = "Passed time in criterion (%)")

ggplot(data.long4, aes(x = Dir_NF, y = Beta, fill = Crit_Type)) + 
  geom_bar(position = position_dodge(width = 1.0), stat = "identity") +   
  scale_fill_manual(values = colors3) +   
  labs(title = "Barplot avec ggplot2", x = "Dir_NF", y = "Beta") + 
  theme_minimal()
```

I try to change the fill part,and look up to the documentation but i should miss something

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to verify and explain the behavior